# How can I align the Flutter Text Widget Vetically?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-text

I am trying to align these text widgets vertically so that they are perfectly centered between the two lines. However, flutter sees the size of the text widget to be as big as the red rectangle behind the text (Background color of text only for illustration purposes) because of the decender line. However, this results in the text looking a bit offcentered. Is there a way to align the text using the baseline and not the decender?

[image]

Comment: best to do this is by wrapping `Text` widget with `Center` widget.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to create this specific layout? It would help replicate the exact design and figure out the right fix... I feel like this can be fixed by having an Expanded and then aligning its child to the center, but need to see the code to be sure.

Comment: Agree with @Sidak this question would be easier to answer if you give us your code and fix it

Answer (score 0):

Play with the text height (line-height)

```
Text('Hey There', 
  style: TextStyle(height: 5, fontSize: 10),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Align widget just wrap your text with Align and provide your alignment

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a center widget

```
Center(
    child: Text(
      "PAYMENT",
      style: TextStyle(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
)
```

Dartpad:

https://dartpad.dev/flutter?null_safety=true&id=3b0bf085892c1867012f5dd00713ccf7

[image: Dartpad result]

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is to use the "**CrossAxisAlignment**" attribute in the **Column** widget.

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Text('Delivery'),
    Text('Payment'),
    Text('Total'),
  ],
)
```